# Error when using ggplot2: can't find `stat` called "identity"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I didn't find any results on my internet calls. How to fix this error is caused?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=disp , y=wt)) +
geom_point(stat = "identity")
```

result;

> Error: Can't find `stat` called "identity"

My `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=tr_TR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=tr_TR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=tr_TR.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=tr_TR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=tr_TR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=tr_TR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=tr_TR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.1.0 shiny_1.2.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0         pillar_1.3.0       compiler_3.5.1    
 [4] cellranger_1.1.0   RColorBrewer_1.1-2 later_0.7.5       
 [7] plyr_1.8.4         bindr_0.1.1        forcats_0.3.0     
[10] tools_3.5.1        digest_0.6.18      viridisLite_0.3.0 
[13] jsonlite_1.5       tibble_1.4.2       gtable_0.2.0      
[16] pkgconfig_2.0.2    rlang_0.3.0.1      ggplotgui_1.0.0   
[19] rstudioapi_0.8     yaml_2.2.0         haven_1.1.2       
[22] bindrcpp_0.2.2     withr_2.1.2        stringr_1.3.1     
[25] httr_1.3.1         dplyr_0.7.8        htmlwidgets_1.3   
[28] hms_0.4.2          grid_3.5.1         tidyselect_0.2.5  
[31] data.table_1.11.8  glue_1.3.0         R6_2.3.0          
[34] plotly_4.8.0       readxl_1.1.0       readr_1.1.1       
[37] tidyr_0.8.2        purrr_0.2.5        magrittr_1.5      
[40] scales_1.0.0       promises_1.0.1     htmltools_0.3.6   
[43] assertthat_0.2.0   xtable_1.8-3       mime_0.6          
[46] colorspace_1.3-2   httpuv_1.4.5       stringi_1.2.4     
[49] lazyeval_0.2.1     munsell_0.5.0      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this error even if I attach shiny. I can only conclude there is something you are not telling us. Have you tried restarting R?

Comment: Yes, i restarted R.

Comment: Did you restart R and then reinstall ggplot2?

Comment: I can't reproduce neither but I'm still using shiny 1.1.0, could you try downgrading shiny?

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3011